# excess trailing concatenation of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that will take a list and convert it to a string separated by `-` or a `,`.

I have to use a loop for this so I came up with the following.

My problem is that I can't get rid of trailing separator. any ideas?

Output is : `String is r-i-n-g-i-n-g-`

should be : `String is r-i-n-g-i-n-g`

```
#A list created for the purpose of converting it to a string)
c_list = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']
# Function to_string() 
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    counter = 0
    mystring = ''
    for n in my_list:
        n = str(n)
        mystring = mystring + n
        mystring = mystring + sep


    return mystring

print('String is', to_string(c_list, '-'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `str.join` method instead:

```
print('String is', '-'.join(c_list))
```

If you need to use a loop, however, you can make adding the separator the first thing to do in your loop instead, but make it conditional on that there is already content in `mystring`, so that it does not add the separator in the first iteration:

```
c_list = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']
# Function to_string()
def to_string(my_list, sep=', '):
    counter = 0
    mystring = ''
    for n in my_list:
        if mystring:
            mystring = mystring + sep
        n = str(n)
        mystring = mystring + n    
    return mystring

print('String is', to_string(c_list, '-'))
```

Comment: I must use a for loop and I have to do this within a function :) but thanks anyway

Comment: @user1815179 Sure. I've updated my answer for your requirement then.

Comment: Well Thankyou for that, could you explain the diference? Of course i'm looking over it, but I'm having trouble understanding the difference :)

Comment: @user1815179 You're welcome. As I've mentioned above, the difference is that I'm adding the separator upfront rather than after each item in `c_list`, so that you can make adding the separator conditional and only add it when there is already something before it (in which case the `if mystring:` condition is `True`), so that the separator won't be added at the beginning of the string.

Comment: yes, I understand now, very nice :) and thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In return statement you can use string slicing to remove trailing delimiter.

```
return mystring[:-1]
```

This will remove the last character in the string.

Comment: excellently sneaky ------ I was trying to concoct this but didn't know how :)